# How to assign Facebook likes from a website to a Facebook page?

Tags: html, facebook

I have a website that presents different companies and to these companies I would like to add a Facebook like button.

My problem is that I don't know how to add to what company the like should be assigned.

Does anyone know how to assign Facebook likes to other companies' Facebook accounts?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: Where can on that page can I find how to change the recipient for the like button. I'm not just looking to inklude a like button that's no problem.

Comment: You set the url to the url you want to be liked

Comment: No, I misread his question. @webmission You are looking for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Comment: Could you please show an example of how that is done?

Comment: @webmission Updated answer with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all on [the official Facebook developer site.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)

All you have to do is put the Facebook URL of the page you want the button to link to, enter the pixel width, and then just click "Get Code".

The site will then generate you some HTML/JavaScript code you can use in your webpages.

Example:

**This** includes the Facebook JavaScript SDK on your page (it's needed for the plugin to work):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then, place the code for the plugin wherever you want it to appear on the page.

Code for the plugin (from the link above):

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
            <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow">Stack Overflow</a></blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```